# of high passion, of moral certainty

Tags: phrase-meaning

For me, the phrase "of high passion, of moral certainty" doesn't give me a clear clue of whose high passion and moral certainty. Democrats' high passion and moral certainty? Or Trump supporters'?

> The New York Times tweeted:

> In Opinion

> “The Trump years were a time of high passion, of moral certainty, of drawing lines in the sand, of despair at the ethical and intellectual vacuity of political foes,” writes
> @NickKristof. “But now it’s time to recalibrate.”

Comment: It's political commentary, so you should expect "weasel words" from skilled writers who are trying to make you adopt their position without you even realising you're being exposed to "persuasive writing". I haven't looked at the source, but I bet the intended implication is "Trump and his supporters were *passionately but mistakenly* certain of their political aims". In context, "Let's recalibrate" just means something like "The new administration will do things differently, and if you're wise you'll adjust your thinking to support them".

Comment: The meaning is very clear. In any case, the grammar is: to be a time of [nouns]. It  refers to the attitude of those who were against the orange man. Those were the ones who despaired at the ethical and intellectual vacuity of their political foes (orange man supporters0. One could not **reasonably** say that orange man opponents were intellectually vacuous...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't specifically refer to anyone. It's a vague statement, written on purpose to raise the very question you've asked.

Answer (score 2):

I take this to mean the writer is referring to both Trump opponents and Trump supporters. A lot of division was caused during Trump's time in office. No matter which side "of the line" a person was on, many people had strong feelings ("passion") one way or the other due to their own personal values ("morals").